# Sandboxing technologies in Linux: snappy vs flatpak comparison?

Tags: linux, sandbox, packaging, package-managers

So now that xdg-app has been renamed to [FlatPak](http://flatpak.org/), can anyone mention a comparison list of things that each solution provides/lacks, other than [Snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_%28package_manager%29) being implemented by Canonical and FlatPak being implemented by Red Hat?

Comment: a strongly negative view of canonical, but still contains useful comparisons https://www.happyassassin.net/2016/06/16/on-snappy-and-flatpak-business-as-usual-in-the-canonical-propaganda-department/

Comment: a comparison of snappy to nix (a slightly different packaging paradigm): https://sandervanderburg.blogspot.com/2015/04/an-evaluation-and-comparison-of-snappy.html

Comment: a comparison of nix to guix (same packaging paradigm): https://sandervanderburg.blogspot.com/2012/11/on-nix-and-gnu-guix.html -- afaik guix is available on Debian as well as it's own Guix SD

Answer (score 3):

It is still too early to tell which one is better.  They're still going through the whole "My application is better than your application" phase, with both sides having the "Not invented here" problem.  There is a good, bad and ugly thing going on right now.  Good because they're finally addressing the issue of cross platform packaging issues, and the fact that there is more than one competing standard, it means both sides are fighting to be the best.  That of course brings better software and both sides will be throwing a lot of money at the problem until one side beats the other.  Bad because they're both at the beginning stages and are claiming things that aren't really true yet.  Both systems aren't fully cross *nix platform yet so the testing phases haven't been completed enough to form an educated opinion.  Ugly because of that old saying.  We have 100 standards? Why do we have so many standards?  We should make an all encompassing standard to rule them all!  End result?  101 standards.

I'm happy they're fighting about this, it means better software for all... Eventually.